# Read SQLite database from the disk using sql.js

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am able to read the file when it is being uploaded using - input type="file", but I want to read the SQLite file from a hard coded path. The documentation for sql.js does provide a solution as given below, but i'm not able to get it working. Please help.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var SQL = require('sql.js');
var filebuffer = fs.readFileSync('test.sqlite');
// Load the db
var db = new SQL.Database(filebuffer);
```

- I hope its very simple and any one using sql.js can answer this.

Comment: Do you get any errors? I *assume* you're using nodejs (what with `readFileSync` and all), so you should tag the question with that

Comment: Where is your file located? If it is not in the current path, you should give exact path. But I think you already done that, are you?

Comment: Yes the example provide in the sql.js documentation uses Node.js, but is there a simpler solution to this? maybe using just the client-side scripting, because I want to access the file locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the problem is in the location of `sql.js` and `test.sqlite` files. If you keep them in the same directory, write the name as `'./sql.js'` `'./test.sqlite'` with dot and slash:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var SQL = require('./sql.js');
var data = fs.readFileSync('./Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite');
var sqldb = new SQL.Database(data);
```

I just run the code above, and it is works fine with Node.js (`node test.js`). My directory has the following files:

- test.js - file from above sample
- sql.js - library file
- Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite - Chinook test database

**UPDATE 2** People from SQL.js recommend to use this code (see [SQL.js wiki](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/wiki/Load-a-database-from-the-server)) for recent versions of SQL.js:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/path/to/database.sqlite', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    var db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);
    var contents = db.exec("SELECT * FROM my_table");
    // contents is now [{columns:['col1','col2',...], values:[[first row], [second row], ...]}]
};
xhr.send();
```

**UPDATE 1** If you need to open SQLite files in the browser, you can use the code below (see the working example [here](http://alasql.org/demo/016sqlite/)):

```
<script src="sql.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadBinaryFile(path,success) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", path, true); 
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var data = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
            var arr = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            success(arr.join(""));
        };
        xhr.send();
    };

    loadBinaryFile('./Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite', function(data){
        var sqldb = new SQL.Database(data);
        // Database is ready
        var res = db.exec("SELECT * FROM Genre");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The thing is, I will be self hosting this asp.net MVC application in a  windows form. Can I still use node.js? or to make things simpler is there any way to read a file from hard coded file path on client-side?

Comment: 1) You can use iisnode package (https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) to host Node.js under ASP.NET. 2) If you want to read Sqlite on the client (in browser), then you need a different code structure, like in the example http://alasql.org/demo/016sqlite/ (I posted the new code as an update to this answer):

Comment: 3) If you need to specify you server file path to the browser, you need to setup your HTTP server (IIS or Node.js) to map the path from "http:// mysite/mypath/myfile.sqlite" to you server path like "/myserverpath/path/path/myfile.sqlite". This setup depends on your web server

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I am getting this error : The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map. I am able to read a plain text file. How can I fix this?

Comment: But when I do something similar to the example, I get this in the div element : {"filename":"dbfile_951670714","db":5287952,"Yb":{}}, but I am not able to read the .sqlite file as it gives the above mentioned error.

Comment: 1) (good solution) You need to add .sqlite MIMe type to your IIS server (read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx) or similar article fo your version of IIS. 2) (bad solution) rename .sqlite database file to another extension, e.g. *.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69373/discussion-between-agershun-and-div).

Comment: I get the error "SQL.Database is not a function." when instantiating. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you included sql.js file into the page?